# MinHash Query Parser for Solr: "sim" param not working as expected & How to normalize "hash_score" result?

Tags: solrj, solrcloud, solr-query-syntax, minhash, lsh

the "sim" param asks me what minimum similarity score I want, I input that. But it seems to fully ignore what minimum score I want and returns me any document that has at least one matching word to the query's string.

Secondly, how do I normalize the returned "hash_score"? since the score is the total number of matching words, it seems.